# Получение разделов и элементов инфоблока

Tags: битрикс

Есть инфоблок. Необходимо вывести все разделы и подразделы, если у подразделов тоже есть подразделы вывести и их ну и соответственно выводить еще и элементы этих подразделов.

На форуме нашел следующее:

```
<?php
$IBLOCK_ID    = 35;
$arFilter    = Array(
      'IBLOCK_ID'=>$IBLOCK_ID, 
      'GLOBAL_ACTIVE'=>'Y');
$obSection    = CIBlockSection::GetTreeList($arFilter);

while($arResult = $obSection->GetNext()){
   for($i=0;$i<=($arResult['DEPTH_LEVEL']-2);$i++)
    echo "..";
     echo $arResult['NAME'].'<br>';
}
?>
```

но как еще и элементы подразделов выводить?

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас вы работаете с классом CIBlockSection, который отвечает только за вывод разделов.
Для того чтобы вывести элементы вам нужно сделать соответствующий запрос:

```
    $IBLOCK_ID = 35;
    $arFilter = Array('IBLOCK_ID' => $IBLOCK_ID);
    $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(array(), $arFilter);
    while($ar_fields = $res->GetNext())
    {
       echo $ar_fields["ID"].": ".$ar_fields["NAME"]."<br>";
    }
```

В $ar_fields у вас будут поля **элементов** инфоблока номер 35.

Если же нужно сохранить древовидную иерархию, то Вы можете отправлять в массив $arFilter значение с ключом 'SECTION_ID', которое будет содержать айди текущего раздела.

Либо сначала сделать запрос всех элементов, а затем в цикле забирать элементы для нужного Вам раздела по полю 'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID', которое хранит айди родительского раздела.

Надеюсь помогло :)

Comment: Спасибо )).  Немного дороботал  while($ar_fields =$res->GetNextElement()).

Comment: Если Вы используете $ar_fields = $res->GetNextElement(), то нужно дополнительно забирать поля, например $actual_fields = $ar_fields->GetFields()

В случае с $res->GetNext() в $ar_fields уже сразу будут все поля.

В любом случае, рад что Вы смогли решить вопрос :)